# Ember Binding Component Template to Models

Tags: ember.js

Hi I have the following Component Template:

```
test-component.hbs: (produces img tag per model)

{{#each titleModels}}
<div class="item">
    <img {{action "owlItemClicked" id index on="click" }} {{bind-attr src=img}}></img>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Its used in parent template

```
parent.hbs:
{{test-component action="titleClicked" parentController=controller titleModels=model}}
```

On titleClicked action it is suppose to remove the clickedModel and refresh the template to show the removed view.

```
parent-controller.js:
   modelChanged: false,
   actions: {
        titleClicked: function(){
           self.get('model').removeObject(aSelectedModel);
           self.set('modelChanged',true);
         }
   }
```

The test-component observes changes to titlesModel and rerenders the template:

```
test-component.js:

titleModelsChanged: function(){
   this.rerender();
 }.observes('parentController.modelChanged'),
```

this.rerender methos is called successfully and the specific html tag (e.g the one defined below) for the removed model is no longer present in the DOM for html page generated from test-component.hbs as expected.

```
 <img {{action "owlItemClicked" id index on="click" }} {{bind-attr src=img}}></img>
```

The img tags for the remaining models are present when inspecting the dom. However they are not displayed out the actual html page ( i dont see the  actual imgs), even though the are present in the DOM when I inspect the elements.

How do I display the img tags of the remaining models after rerender on the html page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, two small notes. The `<img>` tag must not have a closing tag. So no `<img></img>` but simply `<img>` (or `<img />` alternatively).

The context-changing `{{each}}` as you use it is deprecated in current and future versions of Ember.js. So you should rewrite your component as

```
{{#each titleModels as |titleModel|}}
  <div class="item">
    <img {{action "owlItemClicked" titleModel.id titleModel.index on="click" }} {{bind-attr src=titleModel.img}}>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Now to your question. Given that the `<img>` tags are in the DOM but the actual image is not visible, the problem must be in the `src` attribute of the images. If you open the URL in the `src` in a separate tab, do you see the image you're supposed to see?

The JSBin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mitadovero/edit?html,js,output solves the problem.

Comment: Hi I am currently on "ember": "1.8.1" and in the process of upgrading to the latest stable. Initially when the page is loaded all the <img> tags are loaded per model and you can actually see all the images (so its not a problem with the src). When I click on an image I want to remove it from the view. I can see that it removes it from the models array AND when I call rerender its not present in the inspected DOM. While the the img tags are still present. However I cannot see them in the new rendered HTML page.

Comment: OK I see. I'm not sure if this would solve it, but I don't think you need the call to `rerender`. As far as I know, due to data binding, when you remove the object from the array, Ember will rerender the `{{each}}` loop by itself. Have you tried removing the observer and the call to `rerender`?

Comment: Yeh I already attempted that. When I removed the model from the modelArray (titleModels) I expected it to automatically update the view because of bindings. However that didnt work hence why I attempted the observer+rerender combination

Comment: I created a JSBin which I think shows your situation: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ketusaruze/edit?html,js,output. When I click on an image, it is removed from the list. Is that your desired behavior? Also, I didn't need an observer. Removing an item from the array is sufficient for the view to re-render.

Comment: Hi yorbro ... your JSbin is currently giving me an error. I decided to upgrade to the latest version of ember (to make sure that wasnt causing the issue) ... have had some issues upgrading. will let you know if I continue to have this issue afte the upgrade. appreicate your help so far.

Comment: For some reason it hadn't updated the JSBin with my latest changes, I might have passed the wrong URL. Try this one? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mitadovero/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks yorbro you sufficently answered the question i used your example and slight modified it: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cukeyivozu/edit?html,js,output